# How to Convert EventArgs when wiring events?

Tags: c#, .net, events

In .NET applications, normally events are wired this way:

```
    public event EventHandler<ChangeEventArgs> OnChange
    {
        add { _dependency.OnChange += value; }
        remove { _dependency.OnChange -= value; }
    }
```

However this only works if the events being wired have the same event handler. In my current case, the original event args is proprietary of a library, and I don't want to expose that to the client code. So I have some kind of adapter (ChangeEventArgs). How can I use the code above to convert the event args? I imagine something like below (but below code doesn't work)

```
    public event EventHandler<ChangeEventArgs> OnChange
    {
        add { _dependency.OnChange += Convert(value); }
        remove { _dependency.OnChange -= Convert(value); }
    }
```

or

```
    public event EventHandler<ChangeEventArgs> OnChange
    {
        add { _dependency.OnChange += value(this, Convert(args)); }
        remove { _dependency.OnChange -= value(this, Convert(args)); }
    }
```

Comment: If I didn't misunderstand the question you could write a wrapper for the event that triggers the event, parses the returned event args and returns those to the calling dll.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class SomeClassAdapter
{
    private readonly SomeClass obj;

    public SomeClassAdapter(SomeClass obj)
    {
        this.obj = obj;
        this.obj.SomeEvent += HandleSomeClassSomeEvent;
    }

    private void HandleSomeClassSomeEvent(object sender, SomeEventArgs args)
    {
        OnSomeEvent(ConvertEventArgs(args));
    }

    private MyEventArgs ConvertEventArgs(SomeEventArgs args)
    {
        // the magic goes here...
    }

    protected virtual void OnSomeEvent(MyEventArgs args)
    {
        var handler = SomeEvent;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, args);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> SomeEvent;
}
```

**Update.**
This code uses more complex version of adapter pattern, than your code does. `SomeClassAdapter` is an adapter for `SomeClass` (it has `SomeClass` instance in its private field `obj`).

Client code subscribes to *my* `SomeClassAdapter.SomeEvent`. My code, in turn, subscribes to `SomeClass.SomeEvent`. When `SomeClass.SomeEvent` is fired, my event handler (`HandleSomeClassSomeEvent`) is called. This event handler converts `SomeEventArgs` to `MyEventArgs` and raises `SomeClassAdapter.SomeEvent`.

So, we have the chain: `SomeClass.SomeEvent` -> `HandleSomeClassSomeEvent` -> `SomeClassAdapter.SomeEvent`. Looks like "event proxy".

Comment: Wouldn't you have to implement IDisposable and deregister from the event in the Dispose method as well?

Comment: @Keplerian: It depends. if `obj` lifetime is longer than adapter's one, then yes, it will be good to implement `IDisposable`, and unsubscribe from `obj`'s event. On the other hand, if there are no other references to `obj`, except one in adapter, then it makes no sense to dispose/unsubscribe - when adapter goes out of scope, the same does `obj`, and both become the garbage.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few thing you need to do here, I'd I'm going to assume the return type of your `Convert()` method is going to be called `SupportedChangeEventArgs`

The normal pattern would then be to have:

```
public event EventHandler<SupportedChangeEventArgs> Changed; // per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0eyck3s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
```

Add have a virtual member that raises the event

```
public virtual void OnChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
    if( Changed != null )
    {
        Changed(this, Convert(e));
    }
}
```